# less / css selector values based on selectors from import file outside my control

Tags: less, codemirror

@seven-phases-max  I have refactored my code a few times based mostly on your answers to my stackoverflow.com posts but would like to get your feedback to my latest and hopefully final variation:

Ultimately I ended up using :extend to get copies of css properties of styles not under my control:

Below is example of approach I've used in several places create css from base css/less selectors defined in less files outside of my control and optionally over-ridden in another less file outside my control:

```
.CODE-COLORING-ICON {opacity: 0.0};
```

Below code works works with and w/o above css / mixin line

```
.CodeMirror-gutters:before,
.CodeMirror-gutters:hover:after {
    &:extend(.CODE-COLORING-ICON);
}
```

In other places, I created created empty selectors fearing less would not like an extend like above with ".CODE-COLORING-ICON" not defined.  I was surprised the above code worked.

The end game is to merge css from theme with override values from another file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. As soon as you import some file into another file, the code of both is compiled like they're in the same file (after all this is what import feature is for). If you import a *CSS* file mark it as Less import (see [import options](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options)). Not matching extends generate warning not errors (so you may not notice them depending on how exactly you compile).

Comment: Thank-you so much for your reply. Yes there are way too many warnings. I am exploring another approach.  Still trying to grasp better understanding of mixins, variables and extend.